# Index out of Range - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

```
    var truthArray = [Bool]()
func isStrictlyIncreasing(sameSequence: [Int]) {
    var truthArray = [Bool]()
    for i in 0 ... sameSequence.count-1{
        if sameSequence[i]<sameSequence[i+1] {
            truthArray.append(true)
        }
        else {
            truthArray.append(false)
        }
    }
}

func almostIncreasingSequence(sequence: [Int]) -> Bool {
    for i in 0 ... sequence.count-1 {
        var sameSequence = sequence
        let number = sequence[i]
        sameSequence.remove(at: i)
        isStrictlyIncreasing(sameSequence: sameSequence)
        sameSequence.insert(number, at: i)
    }
    if truthArray.contains(true) {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

In this certain code challenge on CodeFights, you are asked to determine if removing one of the numbers in an array can be removed to leave a strictly increasing sequence.

The things I have tried to clear this error are switching the index beginning at 1 and readjusting the code that way, reducing and increasing the index bounds by 1, and this is probably my third time rewriting this code. But since my knowledge is strictly limited, I can't get very creative with my solution.

The problem I have right now is an index out of range. I know exactly what this means, except I don't know which line of code is causing the problem and why. I would very much appreciate hints more than a direct solution, as I am a beginner and this is a good learning experience.

Any and all help is appreciated! If I can add to this question with more details don't hesitate to tell me! :)

Comment: `if sameSequence[i]<sameSequence[i+1]` Is the line causing your index out of range.  Think about how you are iterating, and what sameSequence.count is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `if sameSequence[i]<sameSequence[i+1]` you will get out of range always

If `sameSequence` size is 10, the `for` will be invoked from `i=0` to `i=9` (10 times). The last iteration will try to access `sameSequence[10]` and you will have an out of bounds exception.

You can fix it by changing the loop to `for i in 0..<sameSequence.count-1 { }` but consider that this could have an impact on your algorithm and your problem solution